# What is difference between MPQ8645PGVT-3010-Z and MPQ8645PGVT-3011-Z?

Tags: power, switch-mode-power-supply, programming, converter, configuration

The both MFG no mentioned above has same datasheet? In datasheet they have mentioned like there is a programming for the configuration.
Link: https://www.monolithicpower.com/en/documentview/productdocument/index/version/2/document_type/Datasheet/lang/en/sku/MPQ8645P/document_id/4944/

Can anyone say, what is the exact difference between these.?

Answer (score 2):

The data sheet is says this: -

[image]

> *Can anyone say, what is the exact difference between these?*

I think you'll need to speak with the supplier or try and work it out yourself by programming a few settings.